# ansible - Get hashi vault secret keys

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, hashicorp-vault

Using hashi_vault module, i am trying to retrieve the secret keys. With the below playbook, i cud able to get all the data & metadata info stored in the HV. But If I want only the username or password from data to be printed, how to get that?

**get_secret_kv.yaml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    mytoken: TOKEN
    myvaultip: 0.0.0.0
  tasks:
    - name: Get secrets from vault
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=platform/data/ansibletest token={{mytoken}} url=http://{{myvaultip}}:8200') }}"
```

**Ansible playbook output:**

```
TASK [Get secrets from vault] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "data": {
            "password": "xasdsa231##$^##^%",
            "username": "sys_admin"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "created_time": "2023-08-18T12:51:24.530115915Z",
            "custom_metadata": null,
            "deletion_time": "",
            "destroyed": false,
            "version": 1
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following task, but got the err.

```
debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=platform/data/ansibletest:username token={{mytoken}} url=http://{{myvaultip}}:8200') }}"

TASK [Lookup and Output Entire Secret from Vault] **************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'hashi_vault'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: The secret platform/data/ansibletest does not contain the field 'username'. for hashi_vault lookup"}
```

Comment: To start with, [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names) => `"{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=platform/data/ansibletest token=' ~ mytoken ~ 'url=http://' ~ myvaultip ~ ':8200') }}"`.

Comment: have you looked at the examples? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/hashi_vault/hashi_vault_lookup.html#examples. Also if you using vault Kv2